# I can't see any view in my first laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel. I'm trying to run my first Laravel project. When I go `http://localhost/my_project` then it's working but when I go http://localhost/my_project/public/index.php, the page is not working.

Also, I tried to copy the index.php on my project root file to the public folder but don't work. Now how can I solve the problem?

The **index.php**:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {

    require $maintenance;
}

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';


$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';


$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);


$response = $kernel->handle(

    $request = Request::capture()

)->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: what's version of your Laravel project? Why you have to copy index file to public folder? It was in public folder from start.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start first fresh project laravel. Please run `php artisan serve`. If you want to see page you want, you must define `route` first. The `route` file located in folder `routes` then open file `web.php`. There you can create a router that goes to the page you want.
Example:

```
Route::get('/my_view', function(){
  return view('test');
});
```

Then make your view file in `Resources->views->test.blade.php`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You need to do some work in terminal to create and start the laravel server. So open your terminal and do the below procedures,

Command for creating a laravel project,

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist projectname
```

Then get into the project and start the laravel project to see a view

```
cd projectname
php artisan serve
```

The default url and port that laravel works on is `http://127.0.0.1:8000` which you can see in the terminal itself. Type the url and port in the browser where you can see the initial laravel page.

To change or create a view, You need to check `routes/web.php` and `resources/views/welcome.blade.php`. Just change the contents in the `welcome.blade.php` and refresh the browser. You can see changes in the browser.

Also refer the below link for more clarification,

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views

Answer (score 0):

If you start with a new Laravel project.

First, you have to serve using, **php artisan serve**.

Then add **http://127.0.0.1:8000** on your browser

I hope this helps.

In addition, the views are located on **app\resources\views\welcome.blade.php**

The views folder contains the content of the user interfaces of your website, in layman's terms.

You can add blades. I recommend you to learn about routes and blades.